# Dismiss navigation controller and all of its view controllers stack in UIPopupview using a button within one of the views

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopover

I am displaying a UIPopoverView using the code:

```
selectClientPopController= [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navControllerMini"]];
selectClientPopController.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(500, 700);
selectClientPopController.delegate=self;
[selectClientPopController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+120-scrollView.contentOffset.x, cell.frame.origin.y+120,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

This navigation view controller is ued to step through a two TableViewControllers as shown below:

[image: StoryboardImage]

When a cell on the last tableView is pressed, I would like to dismiss the whole popover.
I understand that this probably needs to be done using delegates, however I do not know where to assign the delegates in order to achieve this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Not

```
 // Listen for TableView row selection by setting up delegate. 
 // Basically self if you set the delegate in the same view controller
 YourTableView.delegate = YourViewControllerObjectWhichHasTableView;


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [selectClientPopController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Whenever u need to dismiss the popover just use the above method. Refer the [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/dismissPopoverAnimated:)

Comment: I know that that dismisses the popoverViewController, however this method needs to be called from the view controller that presented the popover